# How to write XPath based on elements in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get XPaths for underlined values in the image below. I have a list of cards which is always different, and I need to grab values from the inside of the highlighted card which has 'highlight' in its class.

When I grab the XPath through inspecting an element in Chrome, I get something like this `//*[@id="rental-asset"]/div/div[1]/div/rdo-nav-card-asset[11]/div/div[1]/div/i` which doesn't work for me since that 11 in brackets is always going to be a different value. How can I create an XPath for these elements based on their unique class?

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem and please avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to get the first underlined thing. I think you should be able to take it from here.

```
//rdo-nav-card-asset/div[contains(@class,'panel') and contains(@class,'highlight')]/div[contains(@class,'panel-heading')]/div[contains(@class,'panel-title')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Split the xpath and iterate in the range they are expected to occur.

Suppose they have that value from 1-22 you can something like this.
This is a python code.

```
str1 = '//*[@id="rental-asset"]/div/div[1]/div/rdo-nav-card-asset['
str2 = ']/div/div[1]/div/i'
for i in range(1, 22):
    str3 = str1 + str(i) + str2
    a = driver.find_element_by_xpath(str3).text
    print a
```

You can grab the other elements or data inside the loop.

Comment below if you have any confusion.

Comment: This way I will get the text value of that element from all the cards and not just from the highlighted one.

Comment: You can use each element xpath and iterate though those xpaths and get the values of elements or you can store the element in a variable and create a sub-xpath to find the elements you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly find the highlight card and use it as the search context of those underline texts.

Code as following:

```
var activeCard = driver.findElement(By.css('rdo-nav-card-asset > div.rdo-card-highlight'));

// the text of 1rd underline
var title = activeCard.findElement(By.css('.panel-title')).getText();

// the text of 2rd underline
var title = activeCard.findElement(By.xpath('.//div[@class='rdo-card-metric'][1]'))
           .getText();

// the text of 3rd underline
var title = activeCard.findElement(By.css('.text-danger')).getText();

// the text of 4rd underline
var title = activeCard.findElement(By.xpath('.//div[@class='rdo-card-metric'][3]'))
           .getText();
```